# exception emyxerror in module mysqlquerybrowser exe at 00111E52

Tags: mysql

Im getting a MySQL error when trying to open: "Exception EMyxError in module MySQLQueryBrowser.exe at 00111E52. Error while loading stored connections. Error Number 3.

[image: Error screen shot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This helps me to solve my error https://lists.mysql.com/gui-tools/1802

Just go to your C Drive

```
  C:\Users\pc world\AppData\
```

search 'MySQL' Folder which contains connection and some other files. Delete that folder and install gui tools again and run. It works for me.

Comment: this save my day

Answer (score 0):

To All of you guys who is experiencing this bug in 2021 or so. This message may appear when you use Windows 10 and it has "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support" active in region settings. Google how to turn it off (it's easy). I was stuck for a weak then suddenly stumbled upon this and it helped.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was:

> exception emyxerror in module mysqlquerybrowser.exe at 00103cd2 error while loading stored connections.error number 11.

To fix this, go to Control Panel > Clock and Region > Region > Administrative > Change system locale >  and uncheck the "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support" option.

Windows will ask you to restart after this.

If you struggle with a faded out checkbox, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67240773/how-to-uncheck-beta-use-unicode-utf-8-for-worldwide-language-support-box-in-w) has the solution.