# How to uncheck "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support" box in windows 10 pc?

Tags: windows-10

I want to uncheck "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support" under Control panel /Region /Administrative/ Change system locale tab. But I am unable to do so. When I uncheck it then click OK and then restart the pc, I found it again checked. When I try to uncheck it and then CLick OK on region setting Tab, but then I found APPLY button on Region tab is faded, so can't apply the setting. Even after clicking OK on Region, I found this box again checked. Please help me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue. After changing the system locale to English(US), I became able to uncheck "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support". After restarting the PC, this setting is saved.